# If in a triangle $ABC$, $b = ( a + c ) \cos \theta,$ find $\sin \theta$

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

If in a triangle $ABC$, $b = ( a + c ) \cos \theta$, find $\sin \theta$
Please help, I wasn't able to figure out how to solve this.

Options :
A)  $\frac{2\sqrt{bc}}{b+c} \cos \frac{A}{2} $
B)  $\frac{2\sqrt{ac}}{a+c} \cos \frac{B}{2} $
C)  $\frac{2\sqrt{ab}}{a-b} \sin \frac{C}{2} $
D)  $\frac{2\sqrt{bc}}{b-c} \sin \frac{A}{2} $

Comment: What's $\theta$?

Comment: As

$$ \sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$$

and you are given that

$$\cos \theta =\frac{b}{a+c}$$

you can find $\sin \theta$ by solving

$$ \sin^2\theta+\Big(\frac{b}{a+c}\Big)^2=1$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I hadn't given you full information

Answer (score 1):

Using $$\cos(\theta)=\frac{b}{a+c}$$ we get by squaring
$$\frac{b^2}{(b+c)^2}=\cos^2(\theta)=1-\sin^2(\theta)$$

Comment: The only thing I could add to your post is something you are probably leaving for the OP to figure out

$$\frac{b^2}{(b+c)^2}=1-\sin^2 \theta\implies \sin\theta=\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{(b+c)^2}}$$

Comment: I'm sorry I hadn't given you full information

Answer (score 0):

$  \cos (\theta) =\frac {b}{a+c} $    $$   \cos (\theta) =\frac{(Sin B)}{(Sin A\,+ SinC )}   $$
 $$ \cos(\theta) = \frac{ Sin (B/2) }{Cos (( A -C)/2)} $$
$$  \cos (\theta) =\frac { Cos( (A+C)/2) }{Cos (( A-C)/2)} $$
$$  \cos (\theta) = \frac {1-(tanA/2)(tanC/2)}{1+(tanA/2)(tanB/2)}$$

Comment: I'm sorry I hadn't given you full information